# private variables in tasks in C#

Tags: c#, variables, task, private

I have a code to convert JPG files. I used tasks to make it faster. It is faster, but it messed up the images and their dates. To me it is like the variables are shared amongst different threads and this is making the variables from an image to be used for the next/another image in the loop. Is there anyway to make sure that all of the variables in the loop are private in the current task/thread?

Here is my code:

```
int intImageW, intImageH, intImageWtmp;
DateTime creationTime, lastWriteTime, lastAccessTime;

Parallel.ForEach(strarrFileList, strJPGImagePath =>
    {
        Bitmap bmpDest = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(strJPGImagePath);
        lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(strJPGImagePath);
        lastAccessTime = File.GetLastAccessTime(strJPGImagePath);

        using (Bitmap bmpOrig = new Bitmap(strJPGImagePath))
        {
            //Bitmap bmpOrig = new Bitmap(strJPGImagePath);
            intImageW = bmpOrig.Width;
            intImageH = bmpOrig.Height;

            if ((intImageW > intImageH) && (intImageW > intLongSide))
            {
                intImageH = (int)((double)intImageH / ((double)intImageW / (double)intLongSide));
                intImageW = intLongSide;
            }
            else if ((intImageH > intImageW) && (intImageH > intLongSide))
            {
                intImageW = (int)((double)intImageW / ((double)intImageH / (double)intLongSide));
                intImageH = intLongSide;
            }
            else if ((intImageH == intImageW) && (intImageW > intLongSide))
            {
                intImageH = intLongSide;
                intImageW = intLongSide;
            }
            else
            {
                // do something
            }

            // FIX THE ORIENTATION
            if (Array.IndexOf(bmpOrig.PropertyIdList, 274) > -1)
            {
                var orientation = (int)bmpOrig.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0];
                switch (orientation)
                {
                    case 1:
                        // No rotation required.
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        bmpOrig.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        bmpOrig.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        bmpOrig.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        bmpOrig.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        bmpOrig.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                        intImageWtmp = intImageW;
                        intImageW = intImageH;
                        intImageH = intImageWtmp;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        bmpOrig.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        bmpOrig.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                        break;
                }
                bmpOrig.RemovePropertyItem(274);
            }

            bmpDest = new Bitmap(bmpOrig, new Size(intImageW, intImageH));
        }

        bmpDest.Save(strJPGImagePath, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        bmpDest.Dispose();
        GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

        File.SetCreationTime(strJPGImagePath, creationTime);
        File.SetLastWriteTime(strJPGImagePath, lastWriteTime);
        File.SetLastAccessTime(strJPGImagePath, lastAccessTime);
    });
```

The issues are from these variables:
intImageW, intImageH, intImageWtmp, creationTime, lastWriteTime, and lastAccessTime.

Comment: Why don't you move them inside the scope

Comment: Similar problem with the question linked as *dublicate*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared a single set of variables and used them in all of the threads at the same time.
That isn't going to work.

Instead, you need to declare the variables inside the lambda expression, so that each task gets its own variable.